# jQuery cycle effect: scrollHorz not working properly

Tags: jquery, html, css

This question has been asked here for many times and I've followed all the given answers but none to my avail. I'm stuck with **'scrollHorz'** of `jQuery cycle` slider. Following is its **HTML**:

```
<div id="cycleNav"></div>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="container">
        <div id="prev"></div>
        <div id="prevOpacity"></div>
        <div id="dvPauseContainer" class="playing" data-is-paused="0"></div>
        <button id="pause"></button>
        <div id="pauseOpacity"></div>
        <div id="slider" class="playing" data-is-paused="0">
            <img src="~/XImages/1.jpg" width="900" height="350" alt="Flight 1">
            <img src="~/XImages/2.jpg" width="900" height="350" alt="Flight 1">
            <img src="~/XImages/3.png" width="900" height="350" alt="Flight 1">
            <img src="~/XImages/4.png" width="900" height="350" alt="Flight 1">
        </div>
        <div class="controller" id="next"></div>
        <div class="controller" id="nextOpacity"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS** is:

```
#wrapper {
    height: 350px;
    position: relative;
    right: 0;
    top: -120px;
}

#container {
    overflow: auto;
}

#slider {
    height: 350px;
    width: 980px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
#slider > img {
    left: 40px !important;
}
#prev {
    background-image: url(/XImages/prev1.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    position: relative;
    left: 0px;
    top: 350px;
    z-index: 99;
}

#prevOpacity {
    background-color: white;
    display: block;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 98;
    top: 300px;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0.5;
    border-radius: 0px 25px 25px 0px;
}

#next {
    background-image: url(/XImages/next1.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    float: right;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 97;
    bottom: 183px;
    right: 0;
    border-radius: 25px 0px 0px 25px;
}

#nextOpacity {
    background-color: white;
    float: right;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 96;
    bottom: 183px;
    left: 50px;
    opacity: 0.5;
    border-radius: 25px 0px 0px 25px;
}

#dvPauseContainer {
    position: relative;
    top: 425px;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    z-index: 94;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

#pause {
    background-color: transparent;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    position: relative;
    top: 385px;
    left: 470px;
    z-index: 94;
    border: 1px ridge white;
    opacity: 0.5;
}

#dvPauseContainer.paused {
    background-image: url(/XImages/play1.png);
}

#dvPauseContainer.playing {
    background-image: url(/XImages/pause1.png);
}

#cycleNav {
    height: 16px;
    position: relative;
    top: 65px;
    left: 440px;
}

a.box {
    background-color: #ccf;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    margin: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

a.activeSlide {
    background-color: #8f8
}
```

and **javaScript** I'm using is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function ($) {
        $('#slider').cycle({
            fx: 'scrollHorz',
            prev: '#prev',
            next: '#next',
            timeout: 0,
            rev: true,
            pager: '#cycleNav',
            pagerAnchorBuilder: buildPagerBox
        });
        function buildPagerBox(i, el) {
            return '<a href="#" class="box"></a>';
        }
        $('#pause').click(function () {
            var slider = $('#dvPauseContainer');
            var isPaused = slider.data('isPaused');
            slider
                .toggleClass('paused', !isPaused)
                .toggleClass('playing', isPaused)
                .data('isPaused', !isPaused);
            $('#slider').cycle('toggle');
        })
        $('#slider').hover(
            function () {
                $(this).cycle('pause');
            },
            function () {
                $(this).cycle('resume');
            })
    });
</script>
```

This code works fine with other effects like `fade` and `scrollDown` etc.,.

Can someone please help me spot the error. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CSS is messing up the plugin. I kept simplifying your code until the problem went away. When I removed your CSS, the plugin started working. Remove your CSS, then add it back until you find the culprit.

Comment: always thought something was wrong with the css...ok...Thank you for the advice and your time.

Comment: No problem bro. In the future, it's good practice to do just what I did to debug: strip the code down to the bare essentials and then add back bit by bit until you reproduce the error.

Comment: Thank you for the note Sir. Definitely (Y).

Comment: `#slider > img {
    left: 40px !important;
}` 

in the .css file was the culprit ... Setting CSS Rule !important was enforcing it and was overriding jQuery cycle effect fx: scrollHorz.